# Special key input not working (Enter, backspace, tab etc)

Tags: c++, glfw

My keypress code works for all keyboard letters but not for keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

```
glfwSetCharCallback(window, character_callback);


void character_callback(GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int codepoint)
{
    char c = codepoint;
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

The function isn't even run when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> but it does work for the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar, how would I go about receiving all key presses?

Comment: The space bar produces a printable ASCII character -- it is not a "special" key, so it isn't surprising it works correctly.

Comment: Any idea how i could get the Enter key code for example? would it be bad practice to use windows input instead?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually, Enter and Tab also produce ASCII characters (carriage return and horizontal tab, resp.), as printable as that produced by the Space bar. But GLFW doesn't want to treat them as textual keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`glfwSetKeyCallback`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga7e496507126f35ea72f01b2e6ef6d155), not [`glfwSetCharCallback`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga556239421c6a5a243c66fca28da9f742), since you're interested in keys instead of characters. See the [Keyboard Input docs](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#input_keyboard) and the [list of keyboard key macros](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__keys.html#gaa06a712e6202661fc03da5bdb7b6e545).

I'm not sure though why <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> don't produce characters: they would normally produce respectively `0x09` and `0x0d` in other toolkits (e.g. freeglut and Qt). But apparently, it's the way GLFW wants it to be, see their issue [*Backspace not reported to character callbacks*](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/993):

> elmindreda commented on Apr 12, 2017 •
>
> Use the key callback for keys like Enter and Backspace. It provides press, repeat and release events.

Comment: that seems to work but now i get multiple inputs when i keydown, is there any way to restrict it to one input / keypress?

Comment: @DylanRobertson check the `action` parameter of the callback, make sure it's not `GLFW_REPEAT`.